# Delete lines matchin a string and followed by a line with another string

Tags: regex, sed

So, I have 30000 files that contains an some extra lines that should be deleted.

```
ATOM   2208  O   LYS   168      12.304 -23.216   0.596  1.00  0.00
ATOM   2209  OXT LYS   168      13.852 -21.707   0.692  1.00  5.19
TER
ATOM   2210  N   ASP   178       2.448 -25.410  -0.746  1.00  5.40
ATOM   2211  HT1 ASP   178       2.706 -25.926   0.119  1.00  0.00
..
TER
END
```

So, I want to remove only the line that has **TER** but followed by a new line starts with **ATOM**. Therefore I don't want to remove if **TER** is followed by anything else.

Is there any way to do this with sed:

I can use this command but it will delete all lines with **TER**:

```
sed -i '/^TER/d' myfile
```

Comment: `sed` may not be your best bet here. This is because it reads on a line basis, so it will read one line and then forget it so trying to delete a word (`TER`) based on a word from another line (`ATOM`) can be difficult (though not impossible). `awk` might be a better choice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I learned a whole lot about sed while trying to figure out this answer so that was cool.

```
sed -i '/^TER$/{N; s/^TER\nATOM/ATOM/}' test.txt
```

Basically it finds a line containing only "TER". It then appends the next line onto this line. If this new string starts with the "TER" followed by a new line and "ATOM" it replaces this with just "ATOM".

I would suggest not doing an inline edit unless you have already made a backup just in case.

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '$!N;/^TER.*\nATOM/!P;D' file
```

Only print lines that don't start with `TER` followed by `ATOM`.